# Word to describe a certain variation of relief

Tags: single-word-requests

What single word can be used to describe feeling relief through a physical action?

For example:

> "Punching the pillow felt ______, because it physically relieved my stress."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking of the word "cathartic." 
It is defined by Oxford Dictionary as

> 'providing psychological relief through the open expression of strong emotions; causing catharsis':
>   "*crying is a cathartic release*"

Might that be the one you're looking for?

Comment: I think your choice of word might be on point. May we have a dictionary definition from you. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterPoint On *point* -- nice. :-)

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: The adjective 'cathartic' as defined by Oxford dictionary can be used to describe something 'providing psychological relief through the open expression of strong emotions; causing catharsis' i.e. "crying is a cathartic release"

Comment: Comments are temporary and not searchable. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Catharsis, which means psychological or emotional purgation or cleansing after an activity(especially art or literature) may be an applicable word here. However, I don't think it expresses physical actions like punching. You may feel cathartic after seeing a movie or reading a book not after punching a pillow. I think the general consensus on CATHARSIS as the answer to this particular question stems from want of a better and more appropriate word. For instance, there is LALOCHEZIA which is defined as DEPLOYING VULGAR, OFFENSIVE AND OFTEN VOCIFEROUS WORDS IN ORDER TO RELIEVE STRESS OR TENSION.

Comment: lalochezia
The American Heritage® Stedman's Medical Dictionary
Copyright © 2002, 2001, 1995 by Houghton Mifflin Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Company.
Cite This Source
lalochezia in Medicine
lalochezia lal·o·che·zi·a (lāl'ō-kē'zē-ə)
n.
Emotional relief gained by using indecent or
vulgar language....even this does not explain physical actions like punching.

Comment: @JustinChavez - Would you mind accepting the answer you are enthusiastic about?  Click the checkmark to the left of the answer.  Also, you seem to have enough rep to upvote.  To do that, click the upward-facing triangle to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

People sometimes *vent* their feelings in this way.

M-W:

> **[vent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vent)**
>   *transitive verb*
>
> **3**:  to relieve by means of a vent : *vented himself in a fiery letter to the editor*
>
> She vented her frustrations by kicking the car.
>
> Don't vent your anger on me.
>
> I screamed because I needed to vent.
>
> *noun*
>
> **2**:  an opportunity or means of escape, passage, or release : outlet : *finally gave vent to his pent-up hostility*

Answer (score 0):

How about **release** (or **physical release**)?

From Dictionary.com:

> [**release**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/release?s=t): a freeing or
>   releasing from confinement, obligation, pain, emotional strain, etc.

From M-W:

> [**release**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/release): to
>   set free from restraint, confinement, or servitude: *release pent-up
>   emotions*

Example:

> Hitting the punching bag over and over and over again gave me an
>   incredible feeling of **release** (or **physical release**).